# Что быстрее?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categorys` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=139 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category_product` (
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `id_product` (`id_product`),
  KEY `id_category` (`id_category`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

1. ```
   SELECT * FROM
   `categorys`,`category_product` WHERE
   `id`=`id_category` AND `id_product`=23
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT * FROM `categorys` INNER JOIN
   `category_product` ON
   `id`=`id_category` WHERE
   `id_product`=23
   ```
3. ```
   SELECT * FROM `categorys` WHERE `id`
   IN (SELECT `id_category` FROM
   `category_product` WHERE
   `id_product`=23)
   ```

Comment: 1 и 2 вариант показывают почти одинаковое время, но все-таки 2 чуть чуть быстрее.
3 вариант бьет все рекорды он в 3 раза медленнее чем 2 вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмею предположить, что 2 вариант. Но время выполнения запроса не мерял =)

Только мне кажется правильнее будет так:

```
SELECT * FROM categorys INNER JOIN category_product ON categorys.id=category_product.id_category WHERE id_product=23
```

Comment: поздравляю вы выиграли автомобиль

Comment: уряяяяяя!!!

Comment: Для того чтобы забрать выигрыш отправите на короткий номер 0456 sms со словом Да

Answer (score 3):

На меленьких таблицах мерить бесполезно, результаты будут <5-7ms.

Код на [SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fae5c/4)

По EXPLAIN запросы 1,2 одинаковые, в запросе 3 надо перебирать всю таблицу, вообщем, я бы 3-й не стал использовать.

Comment: На маленьких таблицах можно мерить имея более точную систему измерения

Comment: на маленьких таблицах не используются индексы (будет full scan), поэтому от системы измерения время зависеть не будет, только от погоды в Африке. будут просто какие-то значения, может быть и разные. а 1й и 2й запрос суть одинаковые, в разной записи old-school и ansi соответственно. 3-й запрос - запрос с временной таблицей...